# Dockpanel multiple textblock size?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I would like to fill my Dock panel with 9 textblocks.  I would like the text blocks to fill the entire dock panel.  I have set the height to auto and the vertical/horizontal alignment to stretch.

The textblocks, however, don't fill the entire dock panel.  Any ideas on what can be going wrong.  Thanks

My dockpanel lives in a grid.

```
<Border  DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="White" BorderBrush="DodgerBlue" BorderThickness="5,5,5,5" CornerRadius="10" Margin="2" Height="700">
            <DockPanel >
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="txtID" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto">1</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="txtOAG"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto">2</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="txtFAILURE_ID" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto">3</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="txtWIDTH"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto">4</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="txtHeight"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto">5</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="txtBARCODE_READ"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto">6</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="txtBARCODE_NUM"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto">7</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="txtANOMOLY"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto">8</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="txtTRACECODE"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto">9</TextBlock>

            </DockPanel>
        </Border>
```

Comment: Does it need to be `DockPanel`? Why can't you replace the `DockPanel` with a `Grid` and use rows with shared heights?

Comment: I tried with a stackpanel and I couldnt get it to work.  I know it will work with a grid but there has to be a way to do it with a dock/stack panel.

Comment: No, there really isn't. A StackPanel "stacks" everything together, whereas a DockPanel "docks" to sides and by default, the last child fills the space that is left. You should use a Grid with rows and shared heights.

Answer (score 1):

`DockPanel` "docks" to sides, `StackPanel` "stacks" together. You should use a `Grid`.

Like this (example for 3 rows):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="1" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="2" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="3" />
</Grid>
```